# Changing branches deletes file

Tags: git

I've been trying to find out why but got out of ideas.

I have a Rails project with some branches. When I go from master to branch x, it all works fine.

Whenever I come back to master, my config/application.yml gets deleted.

The file is on .gitignore, I've tried to remove from .gitinore, added to the index, and removed it again, but it keeps being deleted.

Comment: I don't think the file exists in the commit labelled by master.

Comment: Files mentioned in `.gitignore` are considered expendable by Git. Don't put essential stuff in files that you list there.

Comment: Why not just get the file on your branch from the other then commit it here? (`git checkout master` then `git checkout branch_x -- config/application.yml` to get the file)

Comment: @j6t git shouldn't remove files being ignored.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Git does not remove files that are not tracked, if they are *not* in `.gitignore`, but by mentioning a file in `.gitignore` you give Git license to delete it.

Comment: @j6t I’ve just tried this in a git repo, the file is being ignored. That said, neither branch has a commit which deletes the test file.

Answer (score 3):

Expected behavior if you switch from a branch that has a file (branch x) to a branch that doesn't have it (master).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the master branch doesn't have a `config/application.yml` file.

You can bring that file into master by this command

```
git checkout x -- config/application.yml
```

Or merge branch x into master, reset it, and interactively add this file

```
git checkout master
git merge x
git reset HEAD~1
git add config/application.yml
git commit -m "Add config/application.yml"
```